# Setting up Code::Blocks with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, codeblocks

I'm pretty new to programming overall and I'm set out to learn Qt. I'm wondering if there is any way to set up Code::Blocks with QT so I can just use the IDE instead of the QtCreator? I'm not too fond of the Creator and I'm already very used to dealing with Code::Blocks.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you are asking for. Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm looking to do all of my developing in QT with Code::Blocks instead of the QT Creator.

Comment: So what? Do you need to know how to set up Qt libraries? How to import pro files? How to make syntax highlighting with it? How to make auto completion? How to work with Qt 5? Etc, please clarify what exactly you wish to get.

Comment: Oh wow. I guess all of that. Like I said I'm pretty new.

Comment: MrZalib: what is not working for you right now? Why asking?

Comment: I guess I need help with basic setup. Like creating a project that works.

Let me rephrase. When I go to create a new project I have absolutely no clue what to do.

Comment: You do not know how to use Code::Blocks in general? How to create a new project? Why is it qt specific? Please explain the problem at hand. What confuses you, etc.

Comment: I know how to use Code::Blocks to create a new project. I've been doing that and writing empty projects. 

I have QT5 installed. When I go to create a new project with the wizard I see that there is an option to create a QT4 project but not a QT5 project. This is the part that confuses me. Does Code::Blocks lack support for QT5 right now? Or is there something I can do?

Comment: Since you're pretty new to programming overall, you are in for a heap of hurt by not using Qt Creator. Qt Creator is "just" the IDE, like Code::Blocks, but it also integrates Qt help system and Qt/QML-specific debugging, and a bunch of other things that Code::Blocks may or may not support. In addition to all that, Qt Creator comes with Qt 5.x binary installs, so all you need is a supported compiler (I suggest VS 2012) and you'll be all set. You can compile, run and debug any of the numerous examples that come with Qt within seconds after firing up Qt Creator.

Comment: This is very helpful. as I understand it at Creator is supposed to detect mingw which is the compiler that I have installed but it doesn't. I may have to check my mingw install. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: You need to install exactly the same version of mingw that was used to build the Qt that you have installed. Are you sure it's the same version?

Comment: That I am not sure. I couldn't even find the .exe in any of the install folders.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is quite broad, but based on your comment, your problem seems to be that you cannot create a Qt 5 project because the wizard is missing that option.

This seems to have been fixed upstream in October by the patch below. The script was extended to provide you a Qt 5 option in the Wizard.

[Code::Blocks Qt5 Wizard](https://github.com/stahta01/stahta01.github.io/blob/master/CodeBlocks/CB_scriptedwizard/jimmyD-code-blocks-qt5-wizard-ed5717c8d9d2.zip)

You need to make sure to use the appropriate version, or at least backport the change to your version if you can.

Even if this was not possible, you can probably just create a Qt 4 project, and modify the qmake path, the libraries, includes, and if your application is meant to be widget based, add the `widgets` keyword to the `QT` variable, etc.

Note: I would suggest to give some consideration to using QtCreator. You would gain a lot in the long term. It gets a lot more support around Qt than CodeBlocks, but I am not sure about your use case. If you plan to develop with the same IDE other than C++/Qt, CodeBlocks may suit you better for consistency.