# how to configure code::blocks to work with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

i want to know how how to configure code::blocks to work with qt to create QT Applications..
i have installed the latest version of QT that is 5.3.2 and i have QT creator ( but don't want to use it) . can someone explain the Code::Blocks Settings for Qt Development ?  or what the directories and libraries should i add tho the project ??
i tried [this way](http://www.kerrywong.com/2008/07/12/codeblocks-settings-for-qt-development/) but i didn't find the directories in the article.

Comment: Like the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849987/setting-up-codeblocks-with-qt

Comment: @zybjtu the link that in the answer not working . it giving me "Oops, you've found a dead link."

Comment: i want to know the the directories and libraries of qt5 that should i add to code::blocks.