# Trying to compile Qt/C++ code in Code Blocks

Tags: c++, qt

I am new with QT, so I am not sure how this works. Im trying to compile some C++ code that includes QT code for graphics. I am using the GNU compiler in Code blocks, but whenever I compile it, It gives this error:

> fatal error: QGraphicsRectItem: No such file or directory

So how do I fix this? Is there a different compiler I need?

My include statement is:

```
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
```

Comment: You have to link the Qt libraries, and as I see you are a beginner so you are going to waste unnecessary time, better use QtCreator.

Comment: I would like to learn, so how do I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting up Code::Blocks with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849987/setting-up-codeblocks-with-qt)

Comment: The first thing you should learn is to link libraries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358745/how-to-use-libraries, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862757/how-do-i-link-to-a-library-with-codeblocks, http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849987/setting-up-codeblocks-with-qt

Comment: Read this: http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=18416.0

Comment: So I tried to use QT Creator as recommended, and I'm still getting the same error. No such file: QTGui/QApplication.

Comment: But you have Qt installed?

Comment: how have you installed Qt, what is your OS? shows your .pro and also the file that generates the error.

Comment: I can not advise a solution for the mistake you have made if you do not show information, we are not fortune tellers

Comment: Yes, I have installed QT 5.9. My OS is Windows 10. I will add my .pro and the file that causes the error.

Comment: Do not add it, create another question.!!!, these files do not have to do with the question

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: in Qt5 QApplication is in the module QtWidgets, no longer in QtGui. I think you're reading a Qt4 manual

Comment: I am using MingGw.

Comment: I am making a query to help you, and I have told you that if you have another problem like the one you indicate, create another question.

Comment: Use this manual: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gettingstarted.html :D

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell from the info you provided. There are several problems that yield this error, not configured the files correctly, there is no such header file, ..., etc. The error is clear though.

Qt is a big library that is why we need `qmake` to take care of configuring the files, so theoretically speaking, you can generate Makefile and copy-paste the related data to your code-blocks project. As far as I know, qmake supports Visual Studio and Xcode projects but not sure if there is a tool for code-blocks.