# how to create and setup Qt project in codeblocks?

Tags: c++, qt, installation, codeblocks

I am new to programming and I have created a few projects in Allegro and SDL but I have problem in creating Qt projects, whenever I download Qt version and intall it in bin folder it doesn't work. Please help me!

Tell me the steps to download and setup Qt in Code blocks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting up Code::Blocks with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849987/setting-up-codeblocks-with-qt)

Comment: Why do not you use Qt Creator? Qt is a very large library and it is often difficult to use other IDEs

Comment: **QT** is best for GUI development in C++ but 'QT creator' is the worst possible IDE for me. Whenever I setup QT creator it gives me error and headache. The most obvipous reason is 'QT kit' nowhere to be found!

Comment: @BrainDevloperDimensional, you need to install the whole Qt SDK, which includes the Qt libraries and Qt Creator. You should use the online installer from this page: https://www.qt.io/download

Comment: That package is over 35GB and my daily internet allowance is 1GB per day, This will be impossible for me.